# how use aggregate functions in child elements using mongodb and c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, grouping

I have a c# class that is a massive collection:

```
public class Usuario_Series_Episodios
{
   public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public int Usuario_Id { get; set; }

    public int Serie_Id { get; set; }

    public IList<EpisodiosVistos> EpisodiosVistos { get; set; }
}

public class Episodes : Entity
{
    public virtual int User_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string  User_Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Serie_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Cod_Serie { get; set; }
    public virtual int Episode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Cod_Eps { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I need to query the most watched episodes of last week grouped by series,my result needs order by descending is like this:

Serie_id --  Episode --  Count

---

1--------------2----------20

---

3--------------4----------19

---

1--------------3----------18

so I did the code below :

```
var collection =db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Usuario_Series_Episodios");
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
           .Group(
            new BsonDocument {
                { "_id", "$EpisodiosVistos.Serie_Id" },
                { "episodio", "$EpisodiosVistos.Episode" },
                { "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) }
            });

var results = await aggregate.SortByDescending(bson => bson["count"]).ToListAsync();
```

but the following error appears :

> Command aggregate failed: the group aggregate field 'episodio' must be
>   defined as an expression inside an object.

someone can help me?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to group by `series_id` and `episodio` correct?  And get the count for each series/episodio grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with the .NET Driver for MongoDB, but below is the idea:

```
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
               .Group(
                new BsonDocument {
                    { "_id", new BsonDocument{{ "series", "$Serie_Id"}, { "episodio", "$EpisodiosVistos.Episode" }} },
                    { "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) }
                });
```

If you want to group by multiple fields, they both need to be included in the `_id` field for the grouping.  All of the fields after that are accumulators which need to be expressions of some kind, which is why the compiler was complaining about `episodio` not being an expression.