# mongodb group multiple ids in c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using the following schema:
[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haIRd.png)

I am trying to aggregate all the Builds Numbers in Builds and get a count of the pass/fail tests.  I can get the aggregate for the builds, and I can get a total count of tests for each build, but I cannot figure out how to get a count of each Status of the builds.

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<testresult>("results");
        var grouping = new BsonDocument {
            { "_id", "$Builds.BuildNumber" },
            { "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1)  }
        };

        var aggregate = collection.Aggregate().Unwind(x => x.Builds).Group(grouping).ToList();

        foreach (var item in aggregate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - Total: {1}", item[0], item[1]);
        }
```

does anyone have any ideas on how to get the counts I am looking for?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

based on [how use aggregate functions in child elements using mongodb and c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630920/how-use-aggregate-functions-in-child-elements-using-mongodb-and-c) i was able to get it to work with the following.

```
var grouping = new BsonDocument {
            { "_id", new BsonDocument { { "build", "$Builds.BuildNumber" }, { "status", "$Builds.Status" } } },
            { "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1)  }
        };


        var aggregate = collection.Aggregate().Unwind(x => x.Builds).Group(grouping).ToList();
```